# SOLVE - Sum the rows column in case of a specific condition

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a table with `userid` `points` `expires` and i want to sum only all the points that match a specific `userid` and `CURTIME() < expires`.

So i did:

```
select
  *, sum(points) as points
from infraction
where
  userid=13999
  and CURTIME() < expires;
```

But it's returning me the whole column of points and not censoring the following **`CURTIME() < expires`** condition.

**Solve:**

Sorry! my bad, the rest of the rows where in the condition criteria.

My solution was the good solution, and also all the rest of the helpers did i didn't reply to them GJ.

THANKS for all the good helpers, you are excellent.

Thanks for all the helpers.

Answer (score 2):

is `expires` only a time or a complete `datetime`?  In second case you need to compare against `NOW` and not `CURTIME`

```
SELECT sum(points) as points
FROM infraction
WHERE
  userid=13999
  AND NOW() < expires;
```

Comment: can you give an example how your expires data look like .. or say which data typ it is ?

Answer (score 1):

You have no `GROUP BY` clause, but are selecting all columns. You will need to add something like the following:

```
SELECT
  inf.*,
  infsum.points
FROM 
  (SELECT SUM(points) AS points, id FROM infraction GROUP BY id) AS infsum
  JOIN infraction AS inf ON inf.id = infsum.id
WHERE inf.userid=13999 AND CURTIME() < inf.expires
```

This uses a subquery to get the summed points by id (substitute the correct column name for `id`) and joins that against the full table by that id. Again, substitute the correct column for `inf.id` and `infsum.id`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to select the limited set, then sum them...

```
slect sum(points) as points from (select
  *
from infraction
where
  userid=13999
  and CURTIME() < expires
) as temp1
```